# How to add a third bar to a bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]I have three pandas series salary (int), ownership (float), and cover (float).

I can get the two of the series to show up fine on the bar chart but when I try to add the third it messes everything up. What am I missing?

```
salary = np.round(new_player_df.groupby('Team')['Salary'].mean())
ownership = np.round(new_player_df.groupby('Team')['Own'].mean() * 100,3)
cover = new_player_df.groupby('Team')['Cover_Prob'].mean()
salary = salary.sort_values()
ownership = ownership.sort_values()

fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes
ax2 = ax.twinx() # Create another axes that shares the same x-axis as ax.
# ax3 = ax2.twinx() # Create another axes that shares the same x-axis as ax.
width = 0.4

salary.plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, width=width, position=0)
ownership.plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, width=width, position=1)
# cover.plot(kind='bar', color='green', ax=ax2, width=width, position=2) 
ax.set_ylabel('Cover')
ax2.set_ylabel('Ownership')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which y-axis should the third series be plotted on, the primary or secondary one?

Comment: the secondary @BigBen

Comment: Perhaps an easier option than your current approach would be to get your transformed data in a new dataframe, and plot using `secondary_y`, e.g.: `df.plot.bar(ax=ax, secondary_y=['ownership', 'cover'], ...)`